# mallocing a char and null terminator

Tags: c, pointers, memory, null, malloc

if you point a char pointer to a chunk of memory that you just malloc() and feed it characters at position [0], [1], [2], [3],..., [n] does malloc already provide a null terminator '\0' at the end or must i provide it at the last element of the char array?

```
int i;
char B; //has the characters hello
char *A=malloc(5*sizeof(char)); //4 bytes for hello + 1 byte for null terminator?
for(i=0; i<strlen(A);i++)
A[i]=B[i];
```

after the for loop finishes should i add a null terminator to the last element of A or does malloc() already provide it?

Comment: The single character `char B;` cannot contain `hello`.  You might have `char B[] = "hello";` though.

Comment: The call to `strlen(A)` provokes undefined behaviour at least for accessing uninitalised memory.

Answer (score 1):

**YES** you need to put a null terminator explicitly. `malloc` is just returning starting pointer to the block of 5 byte memory.

Comment: in the case of strcpy() it would copy the null terminator? Also what about if i initialize a char to something like: char A[4]="hello";

Comment: `A[4]="hello` is buffur overflow. you need a space for 5 char + '\0' terminator space and yes `strcpy` will copy null terminator too.

Answer (score 1):

After `malloc`, `A` contains garbage value, so you need to assign `\0` explicitly. However, there are several other errors in your code:

Your declaration of `B` is wrong, it should be a `char` array instead of a single `char`.

The string `"hello"` contains 6 elements, including the trailing `\0`, so:

```
char B[] = "hello";
char *A = malloc(strlen(B) + 1);
for(i = 0; i < strlen(B) + 1; i++)
    A[i] = B[i];
```

Or you can simply use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(A, B);
```

Answer (score 0):

Malloc will not provide memory filled with nulls.

As pointed out above, use strcpy and be safe.

I edited out the calloc part. That was wrong.

Comment: must i still provide the 1 byte for it when i malloc? I've read that the null terminator sits outside of the memory area that i can assign chars to.

Comment: You always have to provide one extra byte for null character to terminate your strings properly.